# Creating action based time limit with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to find this on google but it didn't come up anything.

What I'm looking for is:

I have a web app that involves a lot of the same action.

I want to limit users to perform that action a maximum of 25 times per 12 hour period in order to avoid bots.

Not sure if relevant to the problem but I would offer the option to pay to have those limits removed.

Since cookies can't be relied upon I'm looking for a MySQL solution.

If you have troubles understanding what I want think of it as Candy Crush lives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are users logging-in or is it public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

`CREATE TABLE user_actions WITH
id, 
user.id, 
action.id,
action_time`

and then

`SELECT action_time FROM user_actions WHERE user.id = $user_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 25`

Then I have to check if the resulting action_time is smaller than 12 hours.

I will check if it's the desired result when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Since users are authenticated, you could just create a "users_actions_limit" table which stores the relationship and the limit on that relationship. Then just log each action to an actions logging table with a timestamp. Check before allowing the action.

You would probably want to cache it so you're not continuing to hit the database once a user has hit the throttle limit.